# Go: Convert Strings Array to Json Array String

Tags: json, go

Trying to convert a strings array to a json string in Go. But all I get is an array of numbers.

What am I missing?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    var urls = []string{
        "http://google.com",
        "http://facebook.com",
        "http://youtube.com",
        "http://yahoo.com",
        "http://twitter.com",
        "http://live.com",
    }

    urlsJson, _ := json.Marshal(urls)
    fmt.Println(urlsJson)
}
```

Code on Go Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/z-OUhvK7Kk

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By marshaling the object, you are getting the encoding (bytes) that represents the JSON string. If you want the string, you have to convert those bytes to a string.

```
fmt.Println(string(urlsJson))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use directly `os.Stdout.Write(urlsJson)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use stdout output encoder:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "os"
)

func main() {
   json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(urls)
}
```

or a string builder:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "strings"
)

func main() {
   b := new(strings.Builder)
   json.NewEncoder(b).Encode(urls)
   print(b.String())
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json#NewEncoder